# expo react-native sdk 33.0.0 ENOENT archive seems to be corrupted

Tags: react-native, expo

I cloned and tried to start up an old React Native project inside a Windows machine.

I ran `npm install` and it seems it successfully installs everything except when it gets to `react-native`, this is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for react-native@https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz (sha512-/qr69yNpTvBiHpepa1ufF43cCMtUzpaQxmCwG6Kz5Z9XqyoEP1lJaJ/BNFj/Bp9+1+LIHwvrDoPBnfQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Projects\rn-casts-master\rn-starter\node_modules\.staging\react-native-3c53bfaf\Libraries\Components\Touchable\__mocks__' npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Projects\rn-casts-master\rn-starter\node_modules\.staging\react-native-3c53bfaf\Libraries\Components\Touchable'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Projects\rn-casts-master\rn-starter\node_modules\.staging\react-native-3c53bfaf\Libraries\Components'
```

I do not see that it is a deprecated version:
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Anyone with more experience here can guide me as to what is going on with these files?

Answer (score 3):

if you cloned this project, you should try delete the `package-lock.json` and delete the `node_modules`

you can use `rm -rf node_modules`

then run `npm install` again to setup all dependencies in `package.json`